# What are the component's of owner's equity

Tags: accounting

I have two questions about owner's equity.

Firstly, is owner's equity the same as stockholder's equity?

And secondly, I have resources which have show different components of owner's equity. The first states that it is owner's capital minus withdraws plus revenues minus expenses, while the other states that it is contributed capital plus retained earnings.

Which is correct?

1) https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=_IXIqS6svO8C&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=equity+capital+withdrwals+revenue+expense&source=bl&ots=TFoJGE89VC&sig=ACfU3U3zvDZldDeoMaEk6N5lNg8-JxnlcA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiM5MXhltLmAhXt73MBHUaxAUAQ6AEwC3oECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=equity%20capital%20withdrwals%20revenue%20expense&f=false (page 56)

2) https://www.coursera.org/learn/wharton-accounting/lecture/wHDmJ/1-2-1-balance-sheet-equation (6:19)

Comment: The two definitions are the same, since retained earnings is profit not distributed as dividend, and profit is "revenues minus expenses".

Comment: What's the difference between net income and profit? The 2nd link says that net income is revenues minus expenses.

Answer (score 1):

> is owner's equity the same as stockholder's equity?

Considering that the stockholders *are* the owners, then yes.

> The first states that it is owner's capital minus withdraws plus revenues minus expenses, while the other states that it is contributed capital plus retained earnings.

Revenue and expenses are periodic measures, while equity is a point-in-time measure. So unless it's talking about all historic revenue and expenses this is a bit misleading.  If that *is* what it's referring to, then the components are the same, just grouped differently.

Net contributed capital is the total of what has been contributed minus what has been distributed (dividends, share buy backs), while retained earnings is the total historic net profit (revenues - expenses) for the history of the company. So both equations can be expressed as

```
Owners capital - withdraws + total revenues - total expenses
```

So basically equity can be broken down into two major components: Net contributions to the company plus all net profit that has been earned. Those two can be broken down further in different ways.